# C# UserPrincipal - ChangePassword enforces policy but SetPassword doesn't?

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I have an application where admins can set user passwords when the user comes by complaining that they forgot theirs.

My app uses `(UserPrincipal).SetPassword(newPassword);` and that works, but it completely ignores policy, and lets the user set whatever they want. Most things about the policy I can retrieve and apply on my own (like length), but some things are beyond my ability to enforce manually (like history).

ChangePassword, on the other hand, enforces policy, but it requires the old password to function, making it useless for users who forgot their password.

Is there any way to get the best of both methods?

Comment: I thought that `.SetPassword(newPassword)` respected the password complexity policy, but only ignored any password history requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Set the new password to a random string, mail that automatically to the user, and optionally enforce that they have to change their password at the next login.

That way nobody except the user gets the unencrypted password, the random string is very likely to be stronger than any policies dictate and even if you cannot enforce users change their password, they are likely to want to do it instead of remembereing the random string.

Comment: There's a bit of a chicken-egg problem, as they can't check their email without their password, and our policy forbids emailing passwords out of the network.

Comment: ok, that's a nice one. Of course i don;t know this as it wasn;t mentioned :)
Still, even if you have the sysadmin read it out on the phone, a randomly generated string still works nicely. True, your sysadmin knows the PW at that moment, but chances are he is not going to memorize `kshgw328hdi&%$&H#^%` or even write it down as easily as say `OurCompany2013`. The rest still applies :)

Or you can look into sending it by text message to the user's phone :) There are several options to automate the password delivery of course :)